# Generics - Legal alternative for (elements instanceof List<? extends Comparable>)

Tags: java, generics, syntax, instanceof

I have this method which unique parameter `(List elements)` sets elements to a ListModel, but I need to make a validation to see if the generic type implements comparable and since such thing like:

```
if (elements instanceof List<? extends Comparable>)
```

is illegal, I don't know how to do the proper validation.

#### Update

I already have done this validation using:

```
(elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0) instanceof Comparable)
```

but I want to know if is there a cleaner solution for that, using for example reflection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like you really know what exactly you want here.  Comparable is pretty useless on its own - that's why it is now parameterized as Comparable<T> - because you need to know what it is able to compare to.  Even if you are able to get this List of Comparable instances, if they're not comparable to each other (say, the list contains one String and one BigDecimal type), you will *still* get a ClassCastException at runtime, which is what generics are attempting to prevent via compiler errors.

Answer (score 4):

The generic type of a list is [erased at runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). For this to work you need to either require the parameter in the method signature or test each element individually.

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends Comparable> elements) {}
```

OR

```
for (Object o : elements) {
    if (o instanceof Comparable) {}
}
```

If you have control over the code, the former is preferred and cleaner; the later can be wrapped in a utility method call if needed.

Comment: The paremeter must be just List, no generics, as much `List<?>`, because it's for a ListModel that can accept lists whose elements may not implement Comparable. It's just a validation to see if I sort the elements or not. I'm trying to use reflection, but when I make use of `((ParameterizedType) elements.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())` I don't get what I want.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. `instanceof` is a runtime operator whereas generic information is lost at runtime (type-erasure).

Comment: Yes, you're right, didn't remember about the type-erasure! But yet I need to make this happen! (Validate if the elements are implementing Comparable, without doing `if (elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0) instanceof Comparable)`, I think it's too ugly. hehe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Generics guru, but to my understanding the reason you can't do that is that at runtime, there's no distinction between an `ArrayList` and, say, an `ArrayList<String>`. So it's too late to perform the test you want.

Why not just declare your method to accept a `List<? extends Comparable>` instead of a `List`?

In particular, the way you phrased your question makes it sound like you expect the list to *always* contain homogeneous elements, but a plain old `List` doesn't give you any sort of assurance like that.

Comment: I can't make the method accept a `List<? extends Comparable>` because it can accept any list, even a Collection, I just need to check if the elements implement Comparable to make a sorting. I already have `if (elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0) instanceof Comparable)`, but as I said before I think it's too ugly. Trying to know if that's possible with reflection.

Comment: But wait a minute. What if some of the elements support Comparable and some don't? Also, what if, for example, one element is a `String` and another a `Long`? They both implement `Comparable`, but you can't compare them.

Answer (score 1):

To your update: simply making sure that one element implements Comparable is not enough (what if the other ones don't?) And making sure that all of the elements implement Comparable is also not enough to validate (what if they are of different classes that implement Comparable but cannot compare with each other?).

But the bigger question is, why bother validating at runtime anyway? What benefit does that give compared to simply trying to use it and then seeing that it fails (i.e. throws an Exception, which maybe you can catch)?