# Decide how to execute a method based on the type of the input argument in Java

Tags: java, list, methods, return

I have the following method that looks for the vectors (lists of double) that are similar to the input vector `v` in `allVectors` and return their indices (list of int):

```
    public List returnSimilar(List v,List<List<Double>> allVectors);
```

Now if `v` is a `List<Double>` I would like the method to execute a certain set of statements (A-statements) and return `List<Integer>`. If `v` is a `List<List<Double>>` I would like the method to execute another set of statements (B-statements) and return `List<List<Integer>>`.

How can this be done?

Comment: You may possibly want to look into method overloading.. That might be able to help..

Comment: Or you use instanceof: `if (v instanceof List<List<Double>>) { ...` but is not best practice

Comment: agree with @ryekayo. Seems like you want 2 different signatures,s o should be 2 different methods. Kevin: that doesn't seem like good OOP

Comment: @KevinWallis type erasure prevents that. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975054/generics-legal-alternative-for-elements-instanceof-list-extends-comparable for example)

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: It seems that `List<List<Double>>` and `List<Double>` cannot be differentiated as different arguments of two overloaded methods. I get the "name clash: methods have the same erasure" error.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method generic:

```
public <T> List<Integer> returnSimilar(List<T> v, List<List<T>> allVectors);
```

If you really need to implement logic that differs from `T` - introduce overloaded methods.

```
public <T> List<Integer> returnSimilar(List<T> v, List<List<T>> allVectors) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < allVectors.size(); i++) {
        if (allVectors.get(i).isSimilar(v)) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    return result;
}

public <T> boolean isSimilar(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean: "If you really need to implement logic that differs from T - introduce overloaded methods."

Comment: How do I provide different implementations based on different types of v? Execute A-statements if v is a `List<Double>`, and B-statements if v is `List<List<Double>>`.

Comment: added an explanation to the post